VS 2022 (17.10.0) crashes on opening solution
VS 2022 is crashing on opening solutions. Loading VS without opening anything and getting the "recent projects" screen is fine. The moment I open a solution file or select to continue without code it freezes and then crashes.
Event view has logged
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetDependencyProperty(Int16)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_PropertyWithExtension()
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_OneBamlRecord()
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.ReadObject(System.Windows.Baml2006.KeyRecord)
   at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.CreateObject(System.Windows.Baml2006.KeyRecord)
   at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValue(System.Object, System.Object ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValuePrivate(System.Object, System.Object ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(System.Object, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(System.Object, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(System.Object, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(System.Object, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.LookupResourceInDictionary(System.Windows.ResourceDictionary, System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.FindDictionaryResource(System.Object, System.Type, System.Windows.ResourceKey, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.FindResourceInternal(System.Object, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetThemeStyle(System.Windows.FrameworkElement, System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateThemeStyleProperty()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnInitialized(System.EventArgs)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.TryFireInitialized()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnVisualParentChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.FireOnVisualParentChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.AddVisualChild(System.Windows.Media.Visual)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.set_TemplateChild(System.Windows.UIElement)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter+UseContentTemplate.BuildVisualTree(System.Windows.FrameworkElement)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(System.Windows.UncommonField`1<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]>, System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory, Int32, System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary, System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(System.Windows.UncommonField`1<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]>, System.Windows.FrameworkElement)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)


To fix the problem of Visual Studio 2022 crashing when opening a solution, you can try the following steps:
1: Delete all files in this directory: %LocalAppData%\Temp, and then restart Visual Studio.
2: Open a command prompt, go to the VS directory, and run this command to reset Visual Studio settings: devenv /ResetSettings
3: Run the devenv /SafeMode command to try to start Visual Studio in safe mode.
4: In the installer, find the version of Visual Studio you want to repair. Then, select "Repair" from the "More" drop-down menu.
5: If none of the above methods work, you may need to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio.
